# Acceptable posting protocol to Reddit

Tags: reddit

I'm a NOOB to Reddit and I'd like to start posting links from my website. I've read their FAQ and it seems I'm okay with posting content.

My concern is that I may post some content that has already been posted before and I want to be careful I'm not seen as a spammer - I legitimately want to post good content to get users to click to my website. I also intend to search Reddit to see if the content has already been posted.

What would my best approach be on this without upsetting the community and having a negative impact on my website.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend on the subreddit. If the subreddit doesn't state its guidelines or policy regarding posting your own content or reposts in its rules (see the subreddit's sidebar) or its [subreddit wiki/FAQ](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/faq#wiki_do_any_subreddits_have_their_own_faqs.3F), it's best to ask the mods of the subreddit first (through the 'Message the Moderators' link in the sidebar).

The [Reddit FAQ](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/faq#wiki_what_constitutes_spam.3F) has this to say about spam posts:

> #### What constitutes spam?
>
> It's a gray area, but some rules of thumb:
>
> - It's not strictly forbidden to submit a link to a site that you own or otherwise benefit from in some way, but you should sort of consider
>   yourself on thin ice. So please pay careful attention to the rest of
>   these bullet points.
> - If you spend more time submitting to reddit than reading it, you're almost certainly a spammer.
> - If your contribution to reddit consists mostly of submitting links to a site(s) that you own or otherwise benefit from in some way, and
>   additionally if you do not participate in discussion, or reply to
>   peoples questions, regardless of how many upvotes your submissions
>   get, you are a spammer. If over 10% of your submissions are your own
>   site/content, you're almost certainly a spammer.
> - If people
>   historically downvote your links or ones similar to yours, and you
>   feel the need to keep submitting them anyway, they're probably spam.
> - If people historically upvote your links or ones like them -- and we're talking about real people here, not sockpuppets or people you
>   asked to go vote for you -- congratulations! It's almost certainly not
>   spam. But we're serious about the "not people you asked to go vote for
>   you" part.
> - If nobody's submitted a link like yours before, give it a shot. But don't flood the new queue; submit one or two times and see what
>   happens.
>
> To play it safe, write to the moderators of the community you'd like
> to submit to. They'll probably appreciate the advance notice. They
> might also set community-specific rules that supersede the ones above.
> And that's okay -- that's the whole point of letting people create
> their own reddit communities and define what's on topic and what's
> spam.

The [Reddiquette](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/205926439) has this to say about posting your own content:

> **Feel free to post links to your own content** (within reason). But if that's all you ever post, and it always seems to get voted down, take a good hard look in the mirror — you just might be a spammer. A widely used rule of thumb is the 9:1 ratio, i.e. only 1 out of every 10 of your submissions should be your own content.

Answer (score 0):

When posting to Reddit, you need to make consumable content. An infographic or something that doesn't take more than a few seconds to scan.

If you're hoping to post more detailed content, you will want to find a community that will enjoy your content.